# Update Javascript after Async Post Back in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, postback

I have the following code on my website:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="myButton_btn" eventname="Click" />
    </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <script>
                function pageLoad(){
                    window.alert("<%=Session("myVariable")%>"); 
                    }
                }
            </script>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Button ID="myButton_btn" Text="Prev Month" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

The javascript is running everytime I click the button. However, even though my subroutine updates the session variable after clicking the button, I always get the same alert. In other words, the same javascript is run after postback, and it is not updated. I am positive that the session variable IS being changed. Does anyone know why this is happening? I appreciate your input!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried to call `UpdatePanel.Update()` in the myButton_btn.Click-Handler? Therefore i would remove the explicit trigger and set `ChildrenAsTriggers` of panel to false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in the button-handler:

VB.Net

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.UpdatePanel, GetType(string), "alertScript", String.Format("alert('{0}');",Session("myVariable")), true)
```

C#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel, typeof(string), "alertScript", string.Format("alert('{0}');", Session["myVariable"]), true);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. My problem is that my alert was just a mock code, and I don't really know how to modify your code to do that. Could you please explain how it works, or at least point to an online reference? THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @Sebastian: What is your actual javascript function that you want to trigger from button-click? The js that should be injected via RegisterStartupScript can be as long as it is. For readability use a variable for it. JS can be in one line or with line breaks, that makes only difference for readability.

Comment: Well, where would I write my function? because you seem to have split the function really weird, having the alert part on one side and the session part on another...

Comment: @Sebastian: i haven't split the js-function. I've used the String.Format function to use parameters. That makes it more readable and less error-prone(in my opinion). So the part with `{0}` simply will be replaced with `Session("myVariable")`.

Comment: My problem is that I'm running JQuerry, so it's telling me that the input string is not in the correct format. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: @Sebastian: On which line of code do you actually get the `input string is not in the correct format`-Exception? jQuery simply **is** JavaScript, so it makes no difference for `RegisterStartupScript`. Please edit your question and add the code you have so far, so that we can have look what is going wrong.

Comment: I solved my problem. It was all my fault. My site is working fine now. thank you so so so so much for your time and help. I greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: Glad i could help. Consider to accept the answer, otherwise people will think it's still open.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but my hack for handling javascript returned within an updatepanel involves registering a function that looks for the new javascript within any UpdatePanels that were updated and then eval()'s their contents.  Here's a rough example:

Site.Master:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    PageLoadedHandler = function(sender, args) {
        var panels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
        for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
            var scripts = panels[i].getElementsByTagName('script');
            for (var j = 0; j < scripts.length; j++) {
                eval(scripts[j].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoadedHandler);
</script>
```

I'm definitely open to cleaner solutions if anyone has one.