# Refresh the session in Updatepanel on Partial Postback in ASp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, updatepanel

I have one Update panel & in that update panel I have a session.

On Partial post back I have to change the value of session depending on the Dates.
But When I do the partial Postback session is not refreshed Or lost, Dont know . 
On the button click I am changing the session values.
How can I achieve that

**Here Is the HTML**

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePasanel1" 
           UpdateMode="Always"  
               ClientIDMode="AutoID"ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
             <div class="vendor_shift_top">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="cntrol_heading">



            <div class="inner_cntrol_heading_right">

                <div class="cls">


                    <div class="popup_inner">
                        Start Date:
                    </div>


                    <div class="popup_inner">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" ReadOnly="false" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="txt_80" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                                
                    </div>

                    <div class="popup_inner">
                        End Date:                                                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup_inner">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" ReadOnly="false" CssClass="txt_80" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                              
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup_inner">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" ForeColor="White" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server"><img src="../images/search.png" /> Search</asp:LinkButton>                               
                    </div>
                </div>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //On Page Load
                    $(".cls1").click(function () {
                        $(".cls").toggle("blind", 100);
                    });

                    //On UpdatePanel Refresh
                    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                    if (prm != null) {
                        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
                            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                                $(".cls1").click(function () {
                                    $(".cls").toggle("blind", 100);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    };
                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="vendor_shift_top">
        <div class="col-md-12 map_box">
            <script type="text/javascript" class="s">
                //On Page Load
                $(function () {
                    var dataSource = [
                            <%=Session["TotalSalesPurchase"]%>
                    ];

                    $("#chartContainer3").dxChart({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        commonSeriesSettings: {
                            argumentField: "year"
                        },
                        series: [
                            { valueField: "Inward", name: "Purchase" },
                            { valueField: "Outward", name: "Sales" },
                        ],
                        argumentAxis: {
                            grid: {
                                visible: true
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        legend: {
                            verticalAlignment: "bottom",
                            horizontalAlignment: "center"
                        },
                        commonPaneSettings: {
                            border: {
                                visible: true,
                                right: false
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                //On UpdatePanel Refresh
                //var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                //if (prm != null) {
                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
                    //if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {

                    var dataSource = [
                            <%=Session["TotalSalesPurchase22"]%>
                    ];

                    $("#chartContainer3").dxChart({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        commonSeriesSettings: {
                            argumentField: "year"
                        },
                        series: [
                            { valueField: "Inward", name: "Purchase" },
                            { valueField: "Outward", name: "Sales" },
                        ],
                        argumentAxis: {
                            grid: {
                                visible: true
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        legend: {
                            verticalAlignment: "bottom",
                            horizontalAlignment: "center"
                        },
                        commonPaneSettings: {
                            border: {
                                visible: true,
                                right: false
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //}
                });
                //};
            </script>
            <div id="chartContainer3" 
           class="overlap_cls" runat="server" style="width: 100%; height: 340px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" EventName="Click" />
      </Triggers>
  < /asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Session.Remove("TotalSalesPurchase22");

        cm.ds.Clear();
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        arr.Add("@StartDate|" + txtStartDate.Text + "");
        arr.Add("@EndDate|" + txtEndDate.Text + "");
        cm.sp_reader_execute("spSalesPurchase_LineChart_Order", arr);

        string DisplayChartFormat = "";
        while (cm.rs.Read())
        {
            string MonthYear = cm.rs["month"].ToString() + "-" + cm.rs["year"].ToString();
            DisplayChartFormat += "{ year: '" + MonthYear + "', Inward: " + cm.rs["InWardQty"].ToString() + ", Outward: " + cm.rs["OutWardQty"].ToString() + " },";
        }

        string FinalDisplayFormat = DisplayChartFormat.Remove(DisplayChartFormat.Length - 1);
        Session["TotalSalesPurchase22"] = FinalDisplayFormat;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel1, typeof(string), "alertScript", string.Format("alert('{0}');", Session["TotalSalesPurchase22"]), true);
    }
```

Any Help will be appreciated

Thank You

Hardik Parmar.

Comment: be more specific. what are you trying to do, and what happens instead *specifically* ? dropping off your entire code and asking what its not working is off topic on stackoverflow

Comment: I have not drop the whole code & I dud I ma not new to stack overflow I have just paste the part of the code I have already told that on button click my session is not refreshing. Dont know why?

Comment: what do you mean by "refreshing" ? a session is simply a collection of key,value pairs. do you mean that your `Session["TotalSalesPurchase22"]` is not being set? have you tried putting a break point in the button click to see if the click handler is being called ?

Comment: @Denish Parvadia Not worked :(

Comment: @Banana My Dear Friend I have 2 session First Session is called On PAgeload Session["TotalSalesPurchase"] & Second session Session["TotalSalesPurchase22"] is called only on poastback ie on the button click I am suucessfully filling the session on button click but that values are not reflected on the webpage

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
string FinalDisplayFormat = DisplayChartFormat.Remove(DisplayChartFormat.Length - 1);
Session["TotalSalesPurchase22"] = FinalDisplayFormat;

Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('The following errors have occurred: \n" + Session["TotalSalesPurchase22"] + " .');</script>");
```

Comment: Not Working Dear I got this very good link for this updation of session but dont where to out this line ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel, typeof(string), "alertScript", string.Format("alert('{0}');", Session["myVariable"]), true);

Comment: this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900522/update-javascript-after-async-post-back-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

since your button is located inside the update panel, you should not use Async trigger for it. use a regular trigger and it will work fine:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="BT_Test" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="BT_Test_Click"></asp:Button>
        <script>
            alert(<%=Session["test"]%>);
        </script>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="BT_Test"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**c#:**

```
protected void BT_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["test"] = "2";
}
```

Comment: Sir but these leads to whole page load & due to this My whole page is getting loaded I cannot go against my clients requirement thank you